# Firefox profile is throwing a Selenium WebDriverException since I updated to Firefox 63

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have been using the following `Selenium` code to open a fresh `Firefox` profile.

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("profile file path"));
    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions(); 
    firefoxOptions.setProfile(profile);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
    driver.get("application Url");
```

It was working fine until I updated to `Firefox 63` and now I am getting the following error.

```
1540496896005   Marionette  DEBUG   Accepted connection 0 from 127.0.0.1:53310
1540496896006   Marionette  TRACE   0 -> [0,1,"newSession",{"acceptInsecureCerts":true,"browserName":"firefox","capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":true,"browserName":"firefox"}}}]
1540496896006   Marionette  TRACE   0 <- [1,1,{"error":"unknown command","message":"newSession","stacktrace":"WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:178: ... et@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:245:8\n_onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:490:9\n"},null]
Oct 25, 2018 2:48:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: newSession
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
System info: host: 'NRIJCTDU8047923', ip: '10.241.10.83', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:           0x4bb74f - <no info>
   1:           0x4bbea9 - <no info>
   2:           0x43ce8d - <no info>
   3:           0x44ce14 - <no info>
   4:           0x44944a - <no info>
   5:           0x4203e1 - <no info>
   6:           0x407dc7 - <no info>
   7:           0x6d95b9 - <no info>
   8:           0x4173a7 - <no info>
   9:           0x6d38b3 - <no info>
  10:         0x770b59cd - BaseThreadInitThunk
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:83)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse$$Lambda$200.0000000013211B00.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse$$Lambda$202.0000000011F857C0.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake$$Lambda$203.0000000012223A00.apply(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:204)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:969)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:137)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:540)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:163)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:245)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:475)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
at selenium.utilities.SeleniumUtilities.OpenApplicationWelcomePage(SeleniumUtilities.java:35)
at selenium.mogems.MoGemsMainPondek.main(MoGemsMainPondek.java:14)
```

I have tried creating a new profile and also tried the following code.

```
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("Selenium2");
    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
    firefoxOptions.setProfile(myprofile);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to update to the latest geckoDriver.

Comment: Hi buddy - i got exact same problem.
Things were working fine on live server and then next day - i got this error.
does this mean that firefox gets updated automatically on my server ?
if yes - how can i stop automatic updates?

Comment: You can go to the 3 bars in the upper right corner and chose options and then go to General and scroll down to Updates. That does mean you won't get security updates.  I am going to set a reminder on my calendar to keep the geckoDriver updated.

Comment: Hi , 
I have tried this command to stop automatic updates of firefox:
sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to someone else, since I didn't immediately have success from just updating to the latest gecko driver (I was running an older version of selenium stand alone server, 3.6).

I am using facebook/php-webdriver.
After updating to Firefox 63, the combination of Selenium standalone server v3.8.1 and geckodriver 0.23 stopped the error occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I am Case I Update my Gecko Driver its Working Fine Now.Always Try New Gecko Driver .
https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/.